# Where can I find the NuGet packages for Sitecore 9.1?

Tags: nuget

Sitecore 9.1 has been released, but I can't see the 9.1 packages in my normal NuGet feed. Are they not released yet, or has something changed?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sitecore did have 9.1 in its own feed to more closely match the way Sitecore does builds internally. <s>https://sitecore.myget.org/gallery/sc-platform-9-1</s>

But Sitecore heard feedback from the community and the decision was made to move it back into a feed where multiple versions will be together. This will classify all the Sitecore dlls together under the same release version. And will make upgrading easy with the fact that all 9.x versions will be together.

#### Feed Url

https://sitecore.myget.org/feed/Packages/sc-framework-packages

#### Announcement

https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/technical-marketing/posts/sitecore-9-1-now-re-published-on-myget

Comment: Is there a document that details this / why they decided to drop NoReferences support?

Comment: The NoReferences public NuGet builds had a lot of complexity around it. And with Sitecore wanting to deploy the release as a whole, it became more important not to separate the dlls into NoRef dlls. This way, we are using the same deployment strategy that Sitecore uses internally.

Comment: Also start thinking about PackageReference and not traditional NuGet packages.config. It will make the move to 9.1 (No NoRefs) much easier. https://www.waitingimpatiently.com/package-reference-nuget/

Comment: Thanks. Had actually looked into `PackageReference` two months ago but some of the [limitations](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference) were showstoppers (at the time). Is there public documentation about this somewhere, or is it just in Slack?

Comment: Just Slack and Symposium, which is where I heard about it.